# parse deploy - unable to push to git remote in heroku (Forbidden error)

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, deployment

I am using Parse with Heroku.
When I do "parse deploy" to deploy new code, I got this error: (xxx in below is the name of my app in heroku.)

> $ parse deploy
>
> This Node.js webhooks project will be deployed to Heroku.
>
> Successfully set the following vars to heroku:
>
> PARSE_MASTER_KEY ************************************hXSg
>
> PARSE_WEBHOOK_KEY ************************************r6sU
>
> HOOKS_URL https://xxx.herokuapp.com/
>
> MONGOLAB_URI ********************************************************************************************p2v8
>
> PARSE_APP_ID ************************************IqOA
>
> remote: ! Forbidden
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://:99592a13-df80-43fbxxx6@git.heroku.com/xxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
>
> Unable to push to git remote: git.heroku.com/xxx.git

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @fnerdrum pointed out it's caused by Heroku's change in accessing git repos, it's mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1200175940000545/

The work around suggests using the Heroku CLI tool instead of the one from Parse you are using now.

Hers's how I did it from OSX Terminal:

1. You need the repo URL first. When you ran the Parse CLI tool you got an error message. Get the app name from it:

   > Unable to push to git remote: git.heroku.com/**your-app-name**.git
2. Add the git remote:

   ```
   heroku git:remote -a your-app-name
   ```
3. Push changes to remote:

   ```
   git push heroku master
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Parse account -> core -> webhooks and check that your app listed under Heroku Apps. When you click on it you should be taken to heroku dashboard. In case you are using different account for heroku make sure you are added as collaborator in Access section.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Heroku changed the way git repos are accessed. Parse is aware of the problem and working on it. You can track it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1200175940000545/

They also propose a temporary workaround.